# How can I replace Unicode letter emojis with corresponding letter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, emoji

I have a string, for example: " cding question".

I want to replace the "", "", and all Unicode letter emojis for that matter into the corresponding letter like "a", "o", etc.

*Note: Unsure if this helps, but I believe the Unicode letter emojis are referred to as regional indicator symbols.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I ended up figuring out thanks to some direction by ktp. It may not be the most efficient, but it was the best I could figure out for the time being. Open to feedback.

```
//Loop through each character of the text
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    //Check if the character is a emoji
    if (text.charCodeAt(i) >= 255)
        //Check if the character is  or between  
        if (text.codePointAt(i) >= 127462 && text.codePointAt(i) <= 127487)
            //Set the text equal to text with the emoji replaced as a lowercase letter equivalent
            text =
                text.substr(0, i) +
                String.fromCodePoint(text.codePointAt(i) - 127365) +
                text.substr(i + 2);
}
```

Comment: One optimization:  Remove `if (text.charCodeAt(i) >= 255)`.

Answer (score 0):

is this similar to what you are looking for?:

```js
let char = '';
let cp = char.codePointAt(0);
let newChar = String.fromCodePoint(cp % 256);
console.log(newChar);
```

Comment: When logging newChar, the value in the console is æ. However, I do think you're onto something with this approach. I will try to look into it more.